# How to copy database from password protected Mongo Server using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to copy a database from a Mongo Server to my local Mongo instance.

I need to do this through python and am running `Pymongo 3.4`, which doesn't have the `copy_database` method anymore. Instead, I have tried using the `client.admin.command('copydb', ...)` function instead. However, seems that it does not support authentication of the source Mongo Server anymore.

Are there any workarounds to this?

Thanks

Comment: You see ```command()``` method from documentation https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/copydb.html#copying-a-database before copy data you have to authenticate with db.admin.

Comment: @juliansalas That's what the OP is trying to use. But you cannot with SCRAM authentication. And the documentation there actually says that at the bottom of the page. But the question is basically answered with "you cannot". And the reason is because the [mechanism presently used by the shell](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/940a6b62189bface6aec2af698e5e9c4149af258/src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/mongo.cpp#L531) is not yet supported in the wire protocol, and does some pretty low level stuff. In theory you could implement in pure BSON. But it would be tough.

Comment: As for "the need to copy database", then I would suggest any regular application really "should not" have such a need. If you think you need it, outside of trying to write some sort of "administration tool and swiss army knife", then your process is likely flawed and the "need to copy database" should be re-examined. General purpose applications should not care about such things, nor touch things like that at such a low level. If it is "for a tool", then have fun implementing the SASL handshake and raw BSON commands.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any workarounds to this?

As mentioned on the comments, there is currently no workaround to copy an authenticated source MongoDB server to another server via [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/) (version 3.4)

For more explanation on the reason behind it, please read [Blog: PyMongo's 'copy_database'](https://emptysqua.re/blog/good-idea-at-the-time-pymongo-copy-database/)

Depending on the requirements, you could utilise mongo shell method [db.copyDatabase()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/) to copy from one `mongod` to another.